# Add Machine Learning Services with Python and machine learning feature to existing SQL Server 2017

Tags: python, sql-server, machine-learning, bigdata, data-science

How to add SQL Server 2017 with the Machine Learning Services with Python and machine learning feature to existing sql server 2017.I had installed Sql Server 2017 without adding python features to it and now I need them? Can I add these features without reinstalling Sql Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to reinstall entire SQL Server. Just use [Add Features to an Instance of SQL Server (Setup)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/add-features-to-an-instance-of-sql-server-setup)

`New SQL Server stand-alone installation or add features to an existing installation.`

And select desired components:

[image]

<sup>Image source: https://www.sqlshack.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/06/word-image-215.png</sup>

More info: [How to use Python in SQL Server 2017 to obtain advanced data analytics](https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-use-python-in-sql-server-2017-to-obtain-advanced-data-analytics/)

Comment: Thank you for your response.these links solved my problem:)

Comment: @Lukasz-Szozda, Thanks for sharing this.. I read your post and then came across this video where the author mentions that its actually possible to run ML models in a SQL server: https://youtu.be/uJmlsIhR_8A?t=3256. Trying to understand why you need SQL server to run ML models? I can run ML models in any linux/windows machine.. just some python files and a data connection. What's the advantage of running the ML model within a linux server running SQL server?

Comment: What does `in-database` mean?

Comment: @alpha_989 `What's the advantage of running the ML model within a linux server running SQL server?` Security/no data movement over network only results/less overhead/advanced analytics + showing it using SSRS and so on. Basically you could do R/Python on DB instance.